# What is the worst-case time complexity of dequeuing from a two-stack queue?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue, big-o

My homework asks me to determine the worst case running times of the following algorithms. enqueue is easy. That's just constant (I hope, otherwise I'll feel stupid)

The second one is confusing. I asked a similar question yesterday, and got a lot of really helpful answers. I'll give it my best shot.

```
Algorithm enqueue(o)
    in stack.push(o)

Algorithm dequeue()
    while (! in stack.isEmpty()) do    // this just checks for an empty stack, so O(1)
        out stack.push(in stack.pop()) // this do loop runs for as many times as values in the stack, so it is O(N)

    if (out stack.isEmpty()) then
        throw a QueueEmptyException    // this is just an exception, so I assume it is O(1) 

    return_obj ←  out stack.pop()      // I think the rest of the program is linear.
                                       // Although without actually coding it out, I'm not 100% sure I even understand what it does.
    while (! out stack.isEmpty()) do

    in stack.push(out stack.pop())
    return return_obj;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C++

Comment: I think it is pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is to count the number of pushes and pops.  If your queue has n elements in it, then the implementation will do n pushes and n pops to transfer `in` to `out`.  It then does one pop to get rid of the last element, then n - 1 more pushes and n - 1 more pops to put `out` back into `in`.  This is a total of Θ(n) pushes and pops.  Each push and pop takes Θ(1) time (or at least, n pushes and n pops takes Θ(n) time), so the total work done with the stack operations is Θ(n). There's also O(1) extra work done in there for things like error handling, etc.  Therefore, the total work done is Θ(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The implementation in the question differs from what you describe in that dequeueing always moves elements from `in` to `out` and back again. This leads to a best case complexity of O(n) for dequeueing.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a node from the front of a linked list takes constant time. However, it takes linear time to find the last node of a linked list (unless we are careful to maintain a reference to it).